# Intuition behind Neural Network Results?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, classification

I am attempting to build a neural network to classify poisonous mushrooms, however the results are not correct. The model compiles successfully, however can someone provide intuition as to why it is the training results are so seemingly accurate after only a few epochs. This does not seem correct, was an error made in the data preprocessing?

Dataset can be found here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/agaricus-lepiota.data

[image: Network Results]

Here is the code:

```
import keras.utils
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# seed weights
np.random.seed(3)

# import dataset
data = pd.read_csv('agaricus-lepiota.csv', delimiter=',')

# encode labels as integers so the can be one-hot-encoded which takes int matrix
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
data = data.apply(le.fit_transform)

# one-hot-encode string data (now type int)
ohe = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
data = ohe.fit_transform(data)

X = data[:, 1:23]
Y = data[:, 0:1]

# split into test and train set
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=.2, random_state=5)

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, input_dim=22, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=1000, batch_size=25)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One epoch is a lot of iterations (n=training_set_size/batch_size). Considering that you have so many layers and no regularization i would suspect overfitting.

Comment: I would agree however when I reduce the network to only two layers (5 neurons in input layer, 1 in output), it still performs with an accuracy of 100% on the test set after one epoch. It may be the case that this measure is correct, however it seems highly unlikely.

Comment: You can try linear classification (just one output sigmoid neuron) see what accuracy you get, and from that point increase layers to get more accuracy.

Comment: The progression of the accuracy with linear classification: https://imgur.com/a/W52zY

Comment: Thank you Andrey.